# Unable to Rename Window Title Text Via SetWindowText Function

Tags: process, c#-2.0, process.start

I am using SetWindowText Function to rename Window Title it seems to work with Windows program like "notepad" but when trying with other 3rd party program its not working.I am grabbing window handle via Process..MainWindowHandle . I want to spawn firefox and rename its window title this is my requirement.Process is getting launched but Window Title rename is not happening i am getting "Send Error Report" Dialog window.Please Help me out.Below is the code.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace SampleNamespace
{
    public class SampleClass
    {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);

  public static void Main()
        {

   Process p = Process.Start("C:\\Sham\\pg\\Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    SetWindowText(p.MainWindowHandle, "FireFox via Process-Start");
        } // End of Main function (program statup)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working"? Do you get an error, or does the window text just not change? It's very likely that you're changing a different window than is used for the primary browser UI, so your new caption isn't getting reflected where you expect to see it.

Comment: I get an error(Send Report Dialog Window) also window text is not changing. What i want is to change window title of the window which is getting spawned via Process.Start.How can i do that..?

Answer (score 0):

Many programs set their main window titles repeatedly during their execution.

A good example is Firefox which changes its main window title whenever you browse to a new page.  Likewise Notepad will change its main window title whenever you open or save a file to include the name of the latest file.

The only way you can realistically expect to exert control like this is to poll.

Comment: Can some please post a sample code? Wat confuses me is if it works with notepad y not with firefox? My target process is Firefox or Chrome Browser i want its Title Changed. In order to use FindWindow and then use Setwindowtext how am i to find the latest window spawned by process.start. That's the problem i am facing.I want to change the Window Title of the Latest Window only..

Comment: @user What you are trying to do won't work. Firefox will overwrite any value you manage to poke in there as soon as the user browses somewhere else.  It would really be useful if you could explain why you want to do this. It's not normal to poke around changing other programs window captions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may occur because Firefox, google, IE work in few processes to isolate different pages from each other, so if one tab crashes, the other will still alive. Open Windows Task Manager to ensure. (Opera is still dont but thes feature is already planned for future releases).
Possible solution for you is to enumerate all processes with name 'firefox.exe' for instance and change window titles of windows that match some of your criteria.